# Angular `ng-repeat` - how to filter only two properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

At the moment, I have a search box and a repeat list. My repeat list uses an object with many properties.

**JSON**

```
$scope.userlist = [{
  firstName: "Jack",
  lastName: "Smith",
  description: "This is a description"
}, {
  firstName: "Luke",
  lastName: "McDonald",
  description: "My name is Luke, and my friend is Jack"
}]
```

And this is my repeat list:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="user in userList | filter: searchInput as allResults">
  <p>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</p>
</md-list-item>
```

My search boxes model is `searchInput`, and the object is saved to the scope as `$scope.userList`.

If I search for `jack`, both results will be displayed due to both objects containing this search term.

How can I limit my filter to only look within the `firstName` and `lastName` properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your controller

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (user) {
    var keyword = new RegExp($scope.searchInput, 'i');
    return !$scope.searchInput || keyword.test(user.firstName) || keyword.test(user.lastName);
}
```

and your HTML will be:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="user in userList | filter: searchFilter"> 
<p>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</p>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: This is quite a neat solution since it keeps the template nice and clean by just referencing a function instead of a ton of other criteria.

Comment: @Fizzix let me know if it is solving your problem

Comment: This solved my problem. Instead of `keyword.test(user.firstName) || keyword.test(user.lastName)` I simply used `keyword.test(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName)` to match the full name. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this filter

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList | filter:filterUser">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.filterUser = function(user){
    return user.firstName.indexOf($scope.searchInput) !== -1 || 
         user.lastName.indexOf($scope.searchInput) !== -1;
  }
```

You have a example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gjj2w3c8/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<md-list-item ng-repeat="user in userList | filter:{firstName:searchInput}">
  <p>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</p>
</md-list-item>
```